# Shared VPC issue on Nic0 and Nic2 public IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I created a project Called Network under the Orgnization on that I created

VPC-Network
   europe-west2 network-europe-west2c   92.168.1.0/24   192.168.1.1.

Shared-VPC
 I added this above subnet alone with two projects. 
   Project A and Project B

Issue

When I create a VM in Project A and assign Nic0 with shared Network 
I don't want a Public IP address

On Nic1 I allocated default network by Pubic IP address. I could not able to ssh or even ping to that public IP which assign to Nic1.

I am not sure I approach is right. I read the documents but still in a confused state.

Answer (score 0):

[I would leave a comment, but I don't have enough reputation]

First of all, an instance with two different NICs, has a special [configuration](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces). Have you followed those instructions? It looks you might didn't set up the route in the instance.

Have you review the [firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls)? Keep in mind you must allow the connection in the host project.